# Why my php app under docker failed failed Google verification?

Tags: google-chrome, google

I changed my job and in my working browser google-chrome 114.0.5735.90-1 (under home kubuntu 20.04) set up a google account
(I connect to many external apps/services through it)

And launching the application url http://127.0.0.1:8081/auth (this is the hosting of the application launched under docker/php/apache2)
I get an error

> Access blocked: App "myapp name app" failed Google verification
>
> myname@mycompany.com The app "myapp name app" has not been verified by
> Google yet. Until the process is completed, the application is only
> available to testers approved by the developer. If you think you
> should have access to it, please contact the developer. If you are the
> developer of the "myapp name app" application, please see the details
> of the error. Error 403: access_denied

Can you tell me what is this error and how to fit it?

I guess I can sign out of my google account - but I wouldn't want to
How can I remove this protection - I do not need it.
I didn't really understand where it came from - in my opinion after I installed and set up a new google account ...

Can it be controlled by some account console or by external plugins?

Comment: What relation does any of this have to Ubuntu?

Comment: My hosting OS is ubuntu. I am not sure which forum is valid here ?

Comment: Maybe [SO] since this is a development question about Google Cloud